# highcharts hide zoom reset button, call zoom reset programmatically

Tags: button, highcharts, zooming, reset

I have a nice chart in highcharts that the user can zoom into.  I really don't like the built-in ZOOM RESET button, and would like to add my own custom zoom reset button into a nav bar already present.

So my questions are:
1. Is there a way to hide the default highcharts ZOOM RESET button?
2. Is there a method/function I can call to perform the ZOOM RESET?  (I can call that from my own button click)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can pass `resetZoomButton` as `display: none` and call `zoomOut`.

```
chart: {
    resetZoomButton: {
        theme: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }
}

$('#resetZoom').click(function() {
    chart.zoomOut();
});

<input type="button" value="reset zoom" id="resetZoom"/>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MvxQ8/)

Comment: Is there also a callback you can hook into to determine when to show/hide the (custom) zoomreset button?

Comment: found the event (select) in the chart options.  FYI for anyone else.  I wish the documentation were more complete!

Comment: You can use HC callback, 

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options,function(chart){
    console.log('chart generated');
});

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection This worked better for me, as setExtremes don't always trigger

Answer (score 0):

Just get the chart and call zoomout:

```
chart = $("#your-chart").highcharts();
chart.zoomOut();
```